# Installing SQL Server 2012 on VM (Hyper-V)

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2012 on my VM (Hyper-V) on Windows Server 2012 R2. I already prepared the VM as an application server and Web Server in the Server Roles. I would like to install Sharepoint 2013 after this.

1. First, I've downloaded the install-version from the Microsoft Server. I'm opening the setup file.
2. After executing the setup file I'll come to the Setup Support Rules.
3. Support rules in detail: 5 operations completed:
   a) Setup administrator
   b) Setup account privileges
   c) Restart Computer
   d) Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) service
   e) Consistency validation for SQL Server registry keys
4. after this the setup ends and the SQL Server update starts.
5. starting the SQL Server update. In different Youtube videos and web sites I've found 8 and not 6 operations to be completed. Do I miss something?
   a) Setup administrator
   b) Restart computer
   c) WMI service
   d) Consistency validation for SQL Server registry keys
   e) Not clustered or the cluster service is up and online
   f) Cluster group owned by local computer
6. after pressing the 'next'-button I'll get the license terms:
7. then I'll get the features..but the list is empty?!
8. at the end there is only an error:

   > There are no SQL Server instances or shared features that can be updated on this computer.

I can't go any further..

Every help will be appreciated.

Karol

Answer (score 0):

Actually I downloaded only the Service Pack, not the whole program. Because of that was the update searching for the installation files.